# Background Tasks not working in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am working with Discord.py on Linux Mint and I want to use background tasks but I can't seem to make them work. The while loop (see below) is apparently never even entered for some reason.

I tried many very basic examples of background tasks but nothing is working and apart from that discord.py is working just fine and I can do plenty of things that work perfectly fine with it.
Even the print statement in the while loop is not showing up which is very weird.

```py
import discord
import asyncio

TOKEN = '<my-token>'

client = discord.Client()

async def my_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    print("I am showing up!")
    while not client.is_closed:
        print("I am not showing up!")
        servers = client.get_all_servers()
        for server in servers:
            for channel in server.channels:
                await client.send_message(channel, "Some message")
        await asyncio.sleep(1) # task runs every second

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
client.run(TOKEN)
```

So the bot boots up correctly, if I were to have a on_message method it would work (I didn't add it because it is irrelevant). But the background tasks are never done for some reason. Not even a single error message is showing up. As if the background task was ignored. I searched on google but nobody seems to have encountered this issue.

EDIT: Solved. There is a pair of parenthesis missing after `client.is_closed` although all online examples I found didn't use any.

Comment: What version of `discord.py` are you using?  Your code has some deprecated methods from past versions, but I would expect you to see errors if you have mismatched versions.

Comment: My version of `discord.py` is 1.2.3 and my version python is 3.6.7. Which methods are deprecated ? Because I don't have a single warning.

Comment: Methods like `send_message` are from before the 1.0 release. See the migration guide: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html

Answer (score 0):

"@tasks.loop(seconds = 1)" means that the loop is repeated every X seconds. 
You can use "@tasks.loop()" to define loop and "(seconds = 1)" to define after how many seconds the loop repeats. 
To start the loop, you need to add "my_background_task.start()" which means that the background task is the started.


You can add my_background_task.start() as command:

```
@bot.command()
async def mybgtask(ctx):
    my_background_task.start()
    await ctx.send("my_background_task loop has started")
```

Here is code:

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import tasks

TOKEN = '<my-token>'

client = discord.Client()


@tasks.loop(seconds = 1) #The loop repeats every 1 seconds
async def my_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    print("I am showing up!")
    if not client.is_closed:
        print("I am not showing up!")
        servers = client.get_all_servers()
        for server in servers:
            for channel in server.channels:
                await client.send_message(channel, "Some message")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

my_background_task.start()
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: I'm really sorry, I fixed it =)